# How does __consumer_offsets keep offset for two consumers?

Tags: apache-kafka

[image]

Just like the above image, if Consumer A consumes from a Partition and Consumer B from a Consumer Group consumes from the same Partition, how does Kafka manage offset in `__consumer_offsets`?

I want to know how Kafka writes consumer offsets in `.index`, `.log`, `.timeindex` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from docs that can be found here: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#impl_offsettracking

```
Kafka provides the option to store all the offsets for a given consumer group in a designated broker.
```

So, it is per consumer group, not per consumer. Also, this article can be helpful for you: https://medium.com/@felipedutratine/kafka-consumer-offsets-topic-3d5483cda4a6 If you read from consumer offsets topic you will receive data in format `[groupId,topicName,partitionNumber]` .

Answer (score 0):

If there are more than one consumer consuming the topic (consumer in a consumer group), Kafka keeps the offset like the below. (I just like images, they help me understand better :) )

[image]

[image]

[image]

In __consumer_offsets-, there are files like below. That's where the offset are recorded.

[image]

Index file and Log file contain the following (an example) : 
Timeindex file is used like index file helping Kafka quickly find messages on the disk.

[image]

Lastly, the below diagram can give you an idea how the offset is stored in the log file.

[image]

All images are from Google.